# Keeping Large Decimal to multiply with Float Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

I have large decimal values that I need to multiply with floats. Converting the decimal values to floats doesn't retain all the decimals that I need for calculations. How can I multiply the decimal values with floats while retaining the precision of the decimal?

The large decimal values (adj column here) are the product of an np.select function so they can't be read in as floats.

Minimally reproducible sample code:

```
from decimal import getcontext, Decimal
import pandas as pd

adjustment = ["0.235340860", "0.158615282", "0.117625053"]
ltrs = ["a", "b", "c"]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    zip(adjustment, ltrs), columns=["adj", "ltrs"])

df['adj'] = df['adj'].apply(lambda x: Decimal(x))
df['adj'] = df['adj'].apply(lambda x: x.quantize(Decimal('1.000000000')))

df['factor'] = round((df['adj']/(1-1.5*df['adj'])),12)
```

Comment: you shouldn't be able to multiply a `decimal.Decimal` with a `float`. Why don't you just multiply by a  `decimal.Decimal`? e.g. `Decimal('1.5')*df['adj'])`

Comment: "The large decimal values (adj column here) are the product of an np.select function so they can't be read in as floats." it isn't clear what you mean here

Comment: `Decimal('1.5')*df['adj']` returns unsupported operand types

Comment: The data type of the adj column is object.

Comment: Stepping back, it's almost impossible for me to believe you have computations that need more than 17 significant digits.  Nothing on this planet can measure that precisely.

Comment: @tonytone no, it does not return "unsupported operand types", that operation works perfectly fine. And yes, the `dtype` **must** be `object` because you are trying to put python objects in the column. I'm not sure why you are stating this.

Comment: That operation on it's own, `Decimal('1.5')*df['adj']` does work fine. Placing it in the formula above gives me the operand error.